# I want to create a Java Queue into which I push runnables, and execute them one by one. Is this right?

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list, queue

So the below is my first guess at managing the runnables in the queue. They get executed one by one. Only one question at this point:

1. How do I regularly check if the previous thread is still running so as not to begin execution of the second one in the list?

   ```
   Queue<Object> qe=new LinkedList<Object>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

       RunnableObject ro = new RunnableObject();

       qe.add(ro);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < qe.size(); i++) {

       qe.peek().start;
       qe.poll();

   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an ExecutorService which is designed to do this.  Added in Java 5.0 in 2004, it contains a queue and a thread pool.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

es.sumbit(new RunnableObject()); // submit Runnable not Threads.
```

This will re-use the same thread(s) reducing overhead and esuring you never use more threads than number you set, in this case 1, but can be say 5 for a fixed size thread pool.

I suggest you read the [High Level Concurrency Objects tutoria](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html)l

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this will put the item into the queue but not execute it? How can I then execute it

Comment: @TheMightyLlama This will put the Runnable into a queue and and the thread pool will execute it as soon as it can.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused as to whether it would execute the runnable or not. Now onto the next step. Once a day scheduling! Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want `cron` like scheduling I suggest using Quartz. This allows you to runs at say 1:30 AM every week day morning  instead of say every ~24 hours. http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: cron4j looked like another suitable candidate. Thanks again.